# What causes Opcache to manually restart

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, opcache

I've setup opcache with php-fpm but for some reason, it keeps manually restarting. I've not actioned a restart and I've set the force restart timeout to 2700 seconds (2 hours) so the cache shouldn't get cleared.

What causes a manual restart?

```
Array
(
    [opcache_enabled] => 1
    [cache_full] => 
    [restart_pending] => 
    [restart_in_progress] => 
    [memory_usage] => Array(
            [used_memory] => 58506120
            [free_memory] => 478364792
            [wasted_memory] => 0
            [current_wasted_percentage] => 0
        )
    [interned_strings_usage] => Array(
            [buffer_size] => 16777216
            [used_memory] => 5840560
            [free_memory] => 10936656
            [number_of_strings] => 3946503
        )
    [opcache_statistics] => Array(
            [num_cached_scripts] => 1553
            [num_cached_keys] => 3015
            [max_cached_keys] => 16229
            [hits] => 52263
            [start_time] => 1475655854
            [last_restart_time] => 1475662737
            [oom_restarts] => 0
            [hash_restarts] => 0
            **[manual_restarts] => 97**
            [misses] => 1553
            [blacklist_misses] => 0
            [blacklist_miss_ratio] => 0
            [opcache_hit_rate] => 97.114241117883
        )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

After digging [into the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b2fb753e85ce36ffd0141013a6eccbf0043d7392/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c#L800-L820), I found [the "manual_restart" counter](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3d2a6d9bedcadceda9b58deaae774e8551ff294e/ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.c#L2343) is increased every time you call [opcache_reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php).